# The blank final field name may not have been initialized error

Tags: java

Following code is giving compilation error mentioned below at `line 1`

> The blank final field name may not have been initialized

My question is why is this error there as i have already initialized field in its constructor.

```
    public class Test1 {
    private final String name;

    public Test1() {
        name = "abc";
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final Function fs = n -> {
        System.out.println(this.name);// Line 1
        return n;

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have got the final field but have nothings setting it

Comment: Does the error actually say "Line 1"?

Comment: @SteveSmith--Did i mentioned this ??? I said at line number 1

Comment: I'm just clarifying that the problem you have is the problem you think you have and not something else, since your code says the problem is actually at line 10 (approx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During object creation, instance initialisers (i.e. assignments to instance variables and initialisation blocks) get executed *before* a constructor runs and hence, they would need the values to be initialised by then. Following should work:

```
public class Test1 {
    private final String name;

    public Test1() {
        name = "abc";
        fs = n -> {
            System.out.println(this.name);// Line 1
            return n;

        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private final Function fs;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }
}
```